# Use `~/.systemd/*.service` rather than `/etc/systemd/system/*.service`

Tags: systemd

I intent to use `~/.systemd/*.service` for my custom-made services rather than the default `/etc/systemd/system/*.service`. I couldn't figure out. Is it **possible**? How?

---

Well, `~/.systemd/*.service` or any other directory in my home. I just want to use my home directory.

Comment: Is this because you want to give your account multiple back-doors for acquiring superuser privileges?

Comment: `man systemctl | less -p '--user'`

Answer (score -1):

I feel like **something is wrong** with the following method. I just though I'd keep it here:

---

I solved the problem by creating a symbolic link with such a command:

```
sudo ln -svf /home/me/etc/systemd/system/report.service /etc/systemd/system/report.service
```

Also the following line needs to be added to `[Service]` section of `report.service`:

```
After=home.mount
```

... to make sure the `home` is mounted.